# Find count of matched elements in two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

So I want to create a function in js which takes two arrays and compare them and give a score depending on how many spots in the two arrays match. Is it right or it's bd written. I am new on coding.

Another problem I have is when I try to execute it on chrome's console. It says that compare is not defined

```
let score = 0;
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
        if(arr1[j] === arr2[i]){
            score++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Should multiple matches of one sport be counted as well. The score of `[1,2]` and `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]` should be 8?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party on this one, but the reason the function was defined was because you didn't have a closing bracket for the first for loop. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.reduce()` to find count of matched elements:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    compare = (a1, a2) => arr1.reduce((a, c) => a + arr2.includes(c), 0);

console.log(compare(arr1, arr2));
```

Alternatively, you can use `.filter()` to find array of matched elements and use its length to determine the count.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    compare = (a1, a2) => arr1.filter(v => arr2.includes(v)).length;

console.log(compare(arr1, arr2));
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Your reducer could be simply `a + arr2.includes(c)`

Comment: Thanks @georg. No doubt, your approach is clever and cleaner. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

### Updated the code as required by you :

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [3,2,3,4,5];
function compare(arr1,arr2){
  let count=0;
  const max=arr1.length>arr2.length ? arr2.length : arr1.length;
  for(var i=0;i<max;i++){
    if(arr1[i]==arr2[i]){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(compare(arr1,arr2));
```

Comment: I didn't specify that what I want is to count the characters which arein the same spot in both arrays

Comment: You mean- only the characters which are matching and at same index as well ?

Comment: Yes Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Hey @Nilfolquercovarrubias , Updated the code as per your requirement.